# Click + shift on QSystemTrayIcon

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, qt4.8

How can I handle <kbd>⇧ shift</kbd> (or <kbd>⌘ command</kbd> and <kbd>⌥ option</kbd>) + `click` on `QSystemTrayIcon`?

What I've tried already:

```
app = MyApp(sys.argv)

class MyApp(QApplication):
    self.trayIcon = QSystemTrayIcon(self)
    self.trayIcon.activated.connect(self.trayIconActivated)
...
    def trayIconActivated(self):
        print "ACTIVATED", app.keyboardModifiers()
...
```

Always prints (regardless of whether the buttons is pressed):

```
ACTIVATED <KeyboardModifiers object at 0x1002ad498>
```

---

```
def trayIconActivated(self):
    print app.keyboardModifiers() & QtCore.Qt.ShiftModifier
    print app.keyboardModifiers() & QtCore.Qt.ShiftModifier == QtCore.Qt.ShiftModifier
```

Always prints:

```
<KeyboardModifiers object at 0x1002ad4b0> 
False
```

---

Versions:

> PySide 1.1.2
> Qt 4.8.4

Answer (score 0):

You need to test flags for a specific modifier using e.g. `app.keyboardModifiers() & Qt.ShiftModifier`.

Comment: `app.keyboardModifiers() & QtCore.Qt.ShiftModifier, app.keyboardModifiers() & QtCore.Qt.ShiftModifier == QtCore.Qt.ShiftModifier` always returns `<KeyboardModifiers object at 0x1002ad4b0> False`